# How to send data to php server and receive data to android

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie in android programming and I want to sent data to php server and receive data to show in android

but I have no idea to create it, I don't no to use library? and Can give some example for me to practice about it.

ps. sorry my english is not good.

example Myphp "xxx.xxx.x.x/api.php"

```
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$index= $_GET['index'];
$path = "http://xxxxxxx/webservice/&query=".urlencode($keyword)."&index=".$index."";
            $jsondata = file_get_contents($path);
            $jsons = json_decode($jsondata,true);

            echo json_encode($jsons);
```

I want to send `keyword` and `index` from edittext to php server and receive json data to show listview.

Answer (score 0):

HttpURLConnection can be used for get,put,post,delete requests :

```
try {
                // Construct the URL
    URL url = new URL("http://xxxxxxx/webservice/&query="
    +keyword.getText().toString()
    +"&index="+index.getText().toString());
    // Create the request 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
    // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.

            }
            JsonStr = buffer.toString(); //result
} catch (IOException e) {
 }
```

where `keyword` and `index` will be your EditText Variables.

Comment: oh! Sorry I forget to tell name php file `"111.11.11/api.php"` ,can't to use `http://xxxxxxx/webservice/&query="....`

Comment: ok then replace the url with 111.11.11/api.php?&query="
    +keyword.getText().toString()
    +"&index="+index.getText().toString())

Comment: I get error line `return null` Cannot return a value form a method with void result type.

Comment: `connect()` is redundant. The input stream cannot be null, so testing for that is pointless. The exception should be propagated to the caller, not swallowed.

Comment: @EJP Can you give some example to me? Or tell me what library should i do